# Using temporal tables with EF6 - PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

I'm using PostgreSQL as relational database for my EF Core 6 project and I can not figure out how to get temporal tables to work with PostgreSQL after running migration. It works fine if I used SQL Server for it, but I would like to make it work in PostgreSQL.

Provider I use for EFCore:
https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

I follow this guide for temporal tables for EF Core 6
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/

All tables have been created, but not the temporal tables / System-Versioned.

Code:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=my_host;Database=my_db;Username=my_user;Password=my_pw");}
```

Temporal tables using modelbuilder

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Car", c => c.IsTemporal());
```

Is there anything I forgot? It also does not look like a temporal table is created in the migration / model snapshot itself

Comment: PostgreSQL has temporal tables?

Comment: @TheBatman Yes, I mean Postgre should support temporal tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think PostgreSQL supports temporal tables out of the box but the functionality can be enabled using an extension and this might allow you to achieve creating the tables with EF Core.

The extension code can be found here:
https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables

Comment: It would be up to the EF Provider to support 3rd party extensions, and AFAIK NpgSQL doesn't do that